# Writing Function: Plot Bar with plt with optional arguments for plt.title()

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, python-3.5

```
def plot_coexpression(new, gene1='', gene2='', gene3='', gene4='', gene5='', gene6=''):
    X, Y = zip(*new)
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set()
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    %matplotlib inline
    plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
    plt.title('Genes most commonly co-expressed with' gene1="axin", gene2="lef", gene3="lgr", gene4="nkd", gene5="", gene6="", fontsize=40)

    ax = plt.bar(range(len(X)), Y, 0.6, align='center', tick_label = X, color="green") 
    ax = plt.xticks(rotation=90)


  File "<ipython-input-3-a3383d66ce8c>", line 8
    plt.title('Genes most commonly co-expressed with' gene1="axin", gene2="lef", gene3="lgr", gene4="nkd", gene5="", gene6="", fontsize=40)
```

I want to plot the plt bar with plt.title('Genes most commonly co-expressed with' gene1="axin", gene2="lef", gene3="lgr", gene4="nkd", gene5="", gene6="",)

gene1 to gene6 names are optional arguments in my function. if not defined, they should not appear in plot title.

This alternative code does not work either.

```
def plot_coexpression(new, gene1=None, gene2=None, gene3=None, gene4=None, gene5=None, gene6=None):
    X, Y = zip(*new)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
    plt.title('Genes most commonly co-expressed with' gene1, gene2, gene3, gene4, gene5, gene6,"'", fontsize=40)
    ax = plt.bar(range(len(X)), Y, 0.6, align='center', tick_label = X, color="green") 
    ax = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply put arbitrary arguments to a function which does not expect them.

[`plt.title`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.title) expects a string as input.

Generating a string may be done using the `format` method

```
mytitle = "This is my title, containing {gene1}".format(gene1="axin")
plt.title(mytitle)
```